# Cannot load module coreData as CoreData

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

I get this error on my app delegate where I `import CoreData`. From what I've read, it is because I named a project coreData. However I changed the name of the project, then deleted it, and I've deleted everything inside `/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`. If I create a project with CoreData, I get the same error.
I have also deleted the contents of /var/folders/

Any info on how to fix this?

(Xcode 7.2)

Comment: Delete the project and create a new one moving the code

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have a namespace clash with apples own CoreData framework. Rename your project or create a new one with a different name and move your files across.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should create new project with CoreData, because i think you forgot to turn on core data module.

Answer (score 0):

For me I did not have namespace clash or anything. "Clean Build" from the menu helped resolve the issue. (XCode 10, Mojave OSX)

Answer (score 0):

change the name of your project to something else , you have named your app one of the iOS framework