# cannot load module 'realm' as 'Realm' swift 4 Xcode 10

Tags: swift, realm

I'm starting to learn to work with Realm.

My project is run fine and very simple: add object to realm. But suddenly there is a bug:

> :0: error: cannot load module 'realm' as 'Realm'.

When I do `Cmd + Shift + K` to clean my Xcode, my project can run normal. But a moment later that bug appears again. I dont know why. Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide specific code so we can take a look. But I would say you probably have some namespace conflicts. This answer might help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39365235/cannot-load-module-coredata-as-coredata.

Comment: @ajeferson thank you so much. It works for me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot load module coreData as CoreData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39365235/cannot-load-module-coredata-as-coredata)